# De-Authorise iTunes account on my 3 stolen PC's

Tags: itunes, accounts

I have had 3 PC's stolen during a break in. How can I de-authorise my account on these without access to them ?

Answer (score 8):

Follow these instructions from Apples Knowledge Base:

> - Click iTunes Store on the left side of iTunes.
> - If you're not signed in to the store, click the Account button, then
>     enter your account name and password.
> - Click the Account button again (your Apple ID appears on the
>     button), enter your password, and then click View Account.
> - In the Account Information window, click Deauthorize All. *
>
> Note: You may only use this feature once per year. The Deauthorize All
>   button will not appear if you have fewer than two authorized
>   computers. If you need assistance on using this feature, please
>   contact iTunes Store support via email
>   (http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/store/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**Deauthorize All** button](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1420).